# Identify included libraries/modules from Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

#### TL;DR

Given an `.apk` file and its `Manifest.xml` decoded, is it possible to tell which libraries/(ad-)modules it ships bundled with – and if so, how?

#### Detailed question

I've checked with the [Manifest specifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and saw the [`<uses-library />` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) – but that's for shared libraries the app expects to be present on the device it shall be installed onto, and thus (AFAICT) not of relevance in this context. I've also checked several "example `Manifest.xml` files" to see what I would find (and yes, if one knows what to look for, one can e.g. identify AdMob by its declared `<activity />`). But except from "guess-work", I was unable to figure an "structured approach" valid for (mostly) all cases one might encounter in the real-world.

So what I'm looking for is to write a script which I can pass an `.apk` file to, and which then spits out a list of libraries and ad-modules used. I'm not asking you to provide me with that script (though I definitely wouldn't reject if offered that; I wouldn't be surprised to hear someone has done that already) – but rather for the core point of what the "identifiers" would be. General approaches are of course welcome as well. If that includes other calls to e.g. `aapt`, that's of course OK. And if I'm on the completely wrong track, and that information has to be looked for at another place, I'd definitely like to hear those details, too :)

In case it's relevant (e.g. for other "external tools" needed), I'm working on Linux – so Windows tools wouldn't do.

Comment: Related: [How to find all the packages included in an apk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18717248/2533433). The *question* describes quite well what *details* I'm looking for. The [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23874023/2533433) unfortunately takes a different approach (plus seems to be GUI only). // PS: Just found [LibRadar](https://github.com/pkumza/LibRadar) which (from its description) seems capable of what I need. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidManifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file has nothing to do with libraries which used in app. And I don't think that there is a way to get list of used libraries, except to check decompiled code and try to match it by package name. But in case if that code obfuscated with Proguard, I think your goal is almost unreachable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, Divers. I'm sure there must be a way to reach my goal – as otherwise, how can e.g. [AppBrain](http://www.apprain.com/) list which libraries and ad modules an app contains, or how do the corresponding [ad-module checker apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules#group_443) work? The latter are scanning the device too fast to do some on-device decompiling (they might be checking some online references by package name and version, though).

Comment: You gave a link on apprain, so I was very confused ). According to Appbrain, you should use their library in order to use it, correct? If yes, they can just parse your build.gradle file and get here all dependency. As per ad-module, don't they just check permission of app?

Comment: I doubt all apps they list those components for have their library integrated (if you check some examples, they seem to list them for almost all the apps, though it takes some time for those details to "turn up" when a new app/APK is added to the site). Also, if that were a requirement, that library would be listed as well, which it not always is (compare e.g. [their ad detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector) with [denper's](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.denper.addonsdetector) in the resp. "Libraries" section). No idea how they do it.

Comment: Ah: looks like they [maintain their own list](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries) where the library developers can send the specifications for. Still I doubt all ad networks did so :) For that, they require some "Identifying features" – e.g. classes, but also "activities or services need to be added to the manifest" as my question asks for. Unfortunately, that list doesn't seem available for download, nor do I see those "Identifying features" published with the resp. descriptions.